# 'if' statements

Tags: c#, winforms

Im still new to C# and was wondering how one would have multiple things happen when an if condition is met. for example.

```
int number = (Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text)); 
   if (number == 1)
         textbox2.Text = "1";                 
         number2 = 33;           
         textbox3.text = (Convert.ToString(number2));
```

When I do something like this it dosnt complete all the desired results.

P.S If this isnt the right site to go for newbie questions like this does anyone know where I can go? (after research of course).

Comment: Only the first statement after the `if` will be executed. You need to add all the statements into a block scope using `{}` around them in order for them all to be executed.

Comment: You should *really* work your way through the [official guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd) or some other tutorial. (That said, as far as newbie questions go yours is okay.)

Comment: No problem, we're fine with newbie questions. Just show us that you made an effort and format your question well, including the relevant code, and we love to answer your question (you'll even get a couple of upvotes that way :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (number == 1) 
{
    textbox2.Text = "1";                 
    number2 = 33;           
    textbox3.text = (Convert.ToString(RSP));
}
```

Add brackets to group statements together.

Without the brackets, the if-statement will ONLY affect the very next statement: `textbox2.Text = "1";`, and the other statements will *always* be run, regardless of the if-statement.

Comment: The very next statement, not the very next line, you can put the statement right next the if.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a block, using the `{` and `}` characters...

```
int number = (Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text)); 
if (number == 1)
{
    textbox2.Text = "1";                 
    number2 = 33;           
    textbox3.text = (Convert.ToString(RSP));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap it all in curly braces { }

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text); 
if (number == 1)
{
   textbox2.Text = "1";                 
   number2 = 33;           
   textbox3.text = Convert.ToString(RSP);
}
```

Also the parenthesis around your Convert functions are not necessary. Doesn't affect functionality, just general house keeping.

Answer (score 2):

If the statements under the if statement is more than 1, braces are required.

```
   int number = (Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text));  
   if (number == 1) 
   {
         textbox2.Text = "1";                  
         number2 = 33;            
         textbox3.text = (Convert.ToString(RSP)); 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = (Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text)); 
if (number == 1)
 {
     textbox2.Text = "1";                 
     number2 = 33;           
     textbox3.text = (Convert.ToString(RSP));
 }
```

Use curly brackets. This shows the block of code to execute on IF statement

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the block of code in curly braces ({}).

```
int number = (Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text)); 
if (number == 1)
{
    textbox2.Text = "1";
    number2 = 33;
    textbox3.text = (Convert.ToString(number2));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the scope {}

```
int number = (Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text));
if (number == 1)
{
     textbox2.Text = "1";
     number2 = 33;
     textbox3.text = (Convert.ToString(number2));
}
```

OR

```
int number = int.Parse(textbox1.text);
if (number == 1)
{
     textbox2.Text = "1";
     number2 = 33;
     textbox3.text = number2.ToString();
     //the above line can also be written as follows
     //textbox3.text = "" + number2;
}
```

Both will work fine